# Line below a wrapped image

Tags: horizontal-alignment, wrapfigure, line

- **I'm trying to do the following**

[image]

- **but for some reason, the line below the image is going to the right.**

[image]

- **here's the code I'm using**

```
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1mm}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Imagenes/Escudo UN.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{center}
UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE COLOMBIA\\
FACULTAD DE INGENIERIA\\
DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIERIA CIVIL Y AGRICOLA\\
HIDROLOGIA\\
\end{center}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1mm}

{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

- **what can I do?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `wrapstuff` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapstuff}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{title}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1mm}
\begin{wrapstuff}[type=figure,l, width=.2\textwidth]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapstuff}
\begin{center}
UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE COLOMBIA\\
FACULTAD DE INGENIERIA\\
DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIERIA CIVIL Y AGRICOLA\\
HIDROLOGIA\\
\end{center}
\wrapstuffclear
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1mm}

{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very useful package, did yo develop it?

Comment: No. The author is one team member of the [CTeX-org](https://github.com/ctex-org).@YiannisLazarides

Answer (score 2):

Without use of wrapfigure, organizing figure and institution tile in `tblr` table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray} % define tblr tables
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{title}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{hlines=1pt,
                      colspec = {@{} X[c] X[4, c, h] @{}},
                      rowsep  = 5pt
                      }
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    &  {UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE COLOMBIA\\
        FACULTAD DE INGENIERIA\\
        DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIERIA CIVIL Y AGRICOLA\\
        HIDROLOGIA} \\
        \end{tblr}
{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]